# Bolding all words in string between certain characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wanting to take a string and get the JSX to replace all the words in between brackets to be bold. I got it to work with this, but just wondering if there is a better way of going about this?

```
const jsxArray = [];
let unformattedString = "[name] Hi there, my name is [name], I am [age] years old, and I work in the field of [profession]";
const boldStrings = unformattedString.match(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/g);
const notBoldStrings = unformattedString.split(/\[.+?\]/g);
    
let j = 0;
if (boldStrings !== null) {
  notBoldStrings.forEach((notBoldString, index) => {
    if (index === 0 && notBoldStrings === "") {
      // the first word should be bolded
      jsxArray.push(<b>{boldStrings[j]}</b>);
    } else {
      jsxArray.push(notBoldString);
      jsxArray.push(<b>{boldStrings[j]}</b>);
    }
    j++;
  });
} else {
  jsxArray.push(notBoldStrings[0]);
}
```

The expected output would be:
**name** Hi there, my name is **name**, I am **age** years old, and I work in the field of **profession**

Comment: Please include the expected output string.

Comment: Added it. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```js
export default function App() {
 let unformattedString =
   "[name] Hi there, my name is [name], I am [age] years old, and I work in the field of [profession]";

 const boldString = (str, substr) =>{
    str.replaceAll(substr, `<b>${substr}</b>`);
 }

 const strArr = unformattedString.split(" ");
 const formattedString = strArr
   .map((item) => {
     let strBold = item.match(/(?<=\[).+?(?=\])/g);
     if (strBold) {
       return boldString(item, strBold);
     } else {
       return item;
     }
   })
   .join(" ");
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formattedString }} />
  </div>
 );
}
```

To see its result: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sea-b88qb8?file=/src/App.js:24-55)

But about `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, Setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a `cross-site scripting (XSS)` attack. And recommended using the `html-react-parser` package in your React project.

```
 npm install html-react-parser
```

To use:

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser' 
const yourHtmlString = '<h1>Hello</h1>'
```

and in return part:

```
<div>
 {parse(yourHtmlString)}
</div>
```

Comment: Is using the React parser better than the way that I implemented it?